# eclipse doesn't start, no errors shown

Tags: eclipse, ide

I have had Eclipse working and I completed some projects already. However, Eclipse was not responding for no obvious reason (doesn't start at all).

The error am getting in the .log file, and i have included some previous errors, is:

```
.
.
.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.xml.core 4 4 2014-05-06 23:58:03.611
!MESSAGE IStructuredDocumentRegion management failed.
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.StructuredDocumentRegionManagementException: IStructuredDocumentRegion management failed.
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelParser.removeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelParser.java:2249)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelParser.removeStructuredDocumentRegion(XMLModelParser.java:2281)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.XMLModelParser.replaceStructuredDocumentRegions(XMLModelParser.java:2339)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.document.DOMModelImpl.nodesReplaced(DOMModelImpl.java:737)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.BasicStructuredDocument._fireEvent(BasicStructuredDocument.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.BasicStructuredDocument.fireStructuredDocumentEvent(BasicStructuredDocument.java:1198)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.BasicStructuredDocument.internalReplaceText(BasicStructuredDocument.java:1979)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.BasicStructuredDocument.replaceText(BasicStructuredDocument.java:2423)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.BasicStructuredDocument.replaceText(BasicStructuredDocument.java:2408)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.JobSafeStructuredDocument.access$2(JobSafeStructuredDocument.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.JobSafeStructuredDocument$3.run(JobSafeStructuredDocument.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.EditorExecutionContext.execute(EditorExecutionContext.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.JobSafeStructuredDocument.replaceText(JobSafeStructuredDocument.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.BasicStructuredDocument.replace(BasicStructuredDocument.java:2368)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.JobSafeStructuredDocument.access$0(JobSafeStructuredDocument.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.JobSafeStructuredDocument$1.run(JobSafeStructuredDocument.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.EditorExecutionContext.execute(EditorExecutionContext.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.core.internal.text.JobSafeStructuredDocument.replace(JobSafeStructuredDocument.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.projection.ProjectionTextStore.replace(ProjectionTextStore.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.replace(AbstractDocument.java:1184)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.replace(AbstractDocument.java:1210)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.projection.ProjectionDocument.replace(ProjectionDocument.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.DefaultDocumentAdapter.replaceTextRange(DefaultDocumentAdapter.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.modifyContent(StyledText.java:7198)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.sendKeyEvent(StyledText.java:8030)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.doDelete(StyledText.java:2549)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.invokeAction(StyledText.java:7011)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.source.projection.ProjectionViewer.doOperation(ProjectionViewer.java:1470)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.StructuredTextViewer.doOperation(StructuredTextViewer.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.TextOperationAction$1.run(TextOperationAction.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.TextOperationAction.run(TextOperationAction.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jface.commands.ActionHandler.execute(ActionHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.executeCommand(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.press(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:504)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.processKeyEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.OutOfOrderListener.handleEvent(OutOfOrderListener.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1081)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1108)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1104)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmKeyDown(Widget.java:1827)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_KEYDOWN(Control.java:4975)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.WM_KEYDOWN(Canvas.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4643)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2443)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.BidiUtil.windowProc(BidiUtil.java:639)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2549)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
!SESSION 2014-05-09 21:45:15.968 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.I20130605-2000
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-05-09 21:46:20.594
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-05-09 21:46:20.711
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\Emad'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
```

I have checked the environment variables and I have them as follows:

CLASSPATH: ; C:\tomcat7\lib\servlet-api.jar;C:\tomcat7\lib\jsp-api.jar;C:\tomcat7\lib\el-   api.jar;C:\tomcat7\Servlets+JSP;%CLASSPATH%;

JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin

PATH: C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PharosSystems\Core;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\

I have also, started the eclipse.ini with the command `-clean` 
and deleted `.\metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench\workbench.xmi`
while I restarted my machine after each attempt.
I even downloaded a fresh version of Eclipse from a different mirror.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just found the answer for this question 
what i needed to do is to make sure that eclipse identifies the JAVA_HOME
by adding the following command at the beginning of the  eclipse.ini file in the Eclipse folder:

```
 -vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin
```

make sure that they are on two separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

Create Environment Variable as below!

### Go to : right click on My Computer-> Properties-> Advance Settings -> Environmental Variables->

- PATH                                            -
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_02\bin     -

  ### -                                                   -

if problem doen't solve ..Try to re-install the jdk and then u will see no problem there is in opening  eclipse.

Comment: i have tried to re install the jdk, i even tried a newer version, but the problem hasn't been solved.